# cURL PHP and cURL

Tags: codeigniter, curl

I'm having a strange issue. I'm working heavily with PHP cURL, and I have a website that I just can't open.

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            @unlink("/tmp/cookies.txt");
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookies.txt");
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookies.txt");
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.gmail.com");
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/3.5.0.1");
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
            $page = curl_exec( $ch );
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

$info returns :

```
[url] => MASKED
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
```

I installed on the server regular cURL.
So if I do 
  curl domain.com

It works !!
It's the same domain.
I tried clearing up the firewall, and also having cURL use FRESH_CONNECT so it pulls the latest IP for the domain.
Still a no go. Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ip of your server could be blocked.

Did you try :

```
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
```

So the referrer is the actual domain ?

Could you give me the domain name so I could test the problem?

Comment: Yes I did. I added a lot of extra settings as well, like verbose display, and I can't figure it out. Sorry, no domain, as it runs on a development server.